# setitimer signalling seems only to work after fork

Tags: c++, linux, signals, fork, posix

I would like to use the following C++ code to wait for a predefined amount of time (in this example always 2 seconds), but still be interruptible by a signal (that's why I don't use sleep):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int measure() {
  itimerval       idle;
  sigset_t        sigset;
  int             sig;

  idle.it_value.tv_sec  = 2;
  idle.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
  setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &idle, NULL);  // TODO: check return value

  sigemptyset(&sigset);
  sigaddset(&sigset, SIGALRM);  // TODO return values
  sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);

  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);  // TODO return value?
  sigwait(&sigset, &sig);  // TODO check return value
  while(sig != SIGUSR1) {
    cout << "Hohoho" << endl;

    idle.it_value.tv_sec  = 2;
    idle.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &idle, NULL);  // TODO: check return value
    sigwait(&sigset, &sig);  // TODO check return value
  } 

  cout << "Done with measurements." << endl;
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  //if(fork() != 0) exit(0);
  //if(fork() == 0) exit(0);
  return measure();
}
```

I would expect this code to print "Hohoho" every 2 seconds until it receives SIGUSR1. Then it prints "Done with measurements." and exits. The second part works as expected. However, I see no "Hohoho", so it seems to me that the SIGALRM from setitimer somehow is not received. The strange thing is that if I do a fork before, the program works as expected. More specifically, if I uncomment either one of the two fork commands at the end, it works. Hence it does not depend on if it's the parent or child process, but somehow the fork event matters. Can someone explain to me what's going on and how to fix my code?

Thanks a lot,
Lutz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Your `setitimer` is failing because you haven't set it correctly.  Struct `itimerval` contains two structs of type timeval.  You are only setting one and thereby picking up whatever garbage was in local storage when `idle` was declared.

```
       struct itimerval {
           struct timeval it_interval; /* next value */
           struct timeval it_value;    /* current value */
       };

       struct timeval {
           time_t      tv_sec;         /* seconds */
           suseconds_t tv_usec;        /* microseconds */
       };
```

If you want a repeating timer every 2 seconds then set the 2nd set to repeat with the same values.

```
  idle.it_value.tv_sec  = 2;
  idle.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
  idle.it_interval.tv_sec  = 2;
  idle.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, Duck. In my real code, I don't want to set the same time over and over again, but determine the next interval after the alarm. So I should set it_interval to 0 and then reset the timer explicitly like in my code above. I first made a mistake implementing this, but eventually it fixed it. Thanks again.